# MenuItem.setVisible(false) doesn't work in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, toolbar

I have a Fragment1, and i am make newInstance of Fragment1 and start in Fragment1, i.e. my fragment stack is Fragment1 -> Fragment1. I want that in first instance visible item in toolbar menu, but in second instance invisible. When i start first instance, item is invisible, i go to the second instance, in second instance the item is visible, but when i tap button back, i go to first instance, and item is visible, but must be invisible. How i can fix it?

Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
...

@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.t_menu, menu);
        int fragmentCount =  getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(fragmentCount > 0);
```

...

When i move code from onCreateOptionsMenu to onPrepareOptionsMenu, result is same. In `fragmentCount` correct result!

Answer (score 0):

In some occasions, if you forget to add

```
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
```

this will occur.

Answer (score -1):

```
menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(fragmentCount > 0);
```

Right after `setVisible`, triggering

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

is effective?

Comment: Fragment doesn't has 'invalidateOptionsMenu();' , but if i do 'getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();' it is not work