# menuItem.setVisible doesn't work when using a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menuitem, android-toolbar, android-menu

*([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837548/menuitem-setvisiblefalse-doesnt-work-in-fragment) post isn't helpful)*

I'm using this code in `onCreateOptionsMenu` to enable/disable menu items in a fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        this.menu = menu;
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        assert ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar() != null;
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(inEditMode);
        menu.findItem(R.id.signOut).setVisible(!inEditMode);
        menu.findItem(R.id.edit).setVisible(inEditMode);
        menu.findItem(R.id.delete).setVisible(inEditMode);
        menu.findItem(R.id.info).setVisible(inEditMode);
    }
```

However, even when `inEditMode` is `false`, all of the Menu Items are visible. This is inside a fragment, which I am using via `ViewPager`. Here's my `AppCompatActivity`'s XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mastermindcorp.alibdeir.salawat.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorControlNormal" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

I'm not setting a Toolbar in my `Fragment`; I only have my Toolbar in the `Activity`. Should I set my Toolbar in every `Fragment`? If not, why is this issue occuring and how can I fix it?

This worked before I converted my `AppCompatActivity` to `Fragment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had to add:

```
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
```

Not sure why this is needed in `Fragment`s but not in `Activity`s

Answer (score 1):

Try putting that code in onPrepareOptionsMenu() instead, and call invalidateOptionsMenu() when inEditMode changes

Comment: Thanks, but I just forgot to call on the `super` class